# Scaling a real-time D3 line chart with a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a real-time D3 line chart that I'm trying to scale live with a jQuery UI slider. Scale the X axis to be specific. Here's a codepen, also a snippet at the end. The chart is rolling here with random data, take a look:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGdKaE

I really have two problems:

**1)** The X axis itself scales the way I want it to when the slider is moved. But the actual line drawn does not scale correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

**2)** When that particular browser tab (or window if there's only one tab) goes inactive, the page is unresponsive when returning to the tab. For example, if the user browses for a couple minutes with another tab, the whole tab with the chart becomes unresponsive, and only becomes responsive again after a long wait. How should I handle the whole background thing with this kind of real time charting with D3? You can surely replicate this yourself.

Focus on the JS. The HTML is dead simple, as is the CSS, just here for the example.

```js
// D3 CHART
random = d3.random.normal(0, .3);

var n = 500,
  duration = 50,
  now = new Date(Date.now() - duration),
  data = d3.range(n).map(random);

var margin = 40;

// get height from element attributes, otherwise set default
var height = 300 - margin * 2;
var width = $('.panel').width() - margin * 2;

var x = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration])
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([-1, 1])
  .range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return x(now - (n - 1 - i) * duration);
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
    return y(d);
  });

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin + margin)
  .attr("height", height + margin + margin)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var yAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(y.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(5).orient("left"));

var xAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(x.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

var path = svg.append("g")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line);

var transition = d3.select({}).transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .ease("linear");


(function tick() {

  transition = transition.each(function() {

    // update the domains
    now = new Date();
    x.domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration]);

    // push a new data point
    data.push(random());

    // redraw the line, and then slide it to the left
    path
      .attr("d", line)
      .transition()
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(now - (n - 1) * duration) + ")");

    xAxis.call(x.axis);

    // pop the old data point off the front
    data.shift();

  }).transition().each("start", tick);
})();



// X axis range slider
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    var graph = d3.select("#chart");

    $("#slider").slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 750,
      min: 200,
      max: 2000,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        old_n = n;
        n = ui.value;

        // update the domains
        now = new Date();
        x.domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration]);

        path
          .attr("d", line)
          .transition()
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(n - old_n) + ")");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
}
.panel {
  width: 600px;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.line,
line,
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: #000;
}
.slider {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Chart</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
    <div id="slider"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```